# Basic Timesheet table - Using ajax requests and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax

Im basically building a very basic timesheet page. I am having problems getting the output onto a basic HTML table. Problem is, I got 2 list of data, one being the parent and the other the child. Child contains the ID of the parent and im having issues finding an easy way to merge the parent/child data together and output them to look something like this:

```
ID  / Description  / Start            / End              / Hours    / Night or Day?
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    Description1   2016-05-31 10:00   2016-05-31 12:00     2         Day
                    2016-06-02 14:00   2016-06-02 15:00     1         Day
                    2016-06-04 19:00   2016-06-04 20:00     1         Night
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2    Description2   2016-04-06 14:00   2016-04-02 15:00     1         Day
                    2016-06-02 18:00   2016-06-02 22:00     4         Night
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3    Description3   2016-05-30 23:00   2016-05-31 00:00     1         Night
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Etc ...
```

All these fields are entered manually, and I just want to simply output them on a table to review the entered data.

I got started on an example page to show my progress so far:

https://jsfiddle.net/tj6bcjos/2/

Here is my code so far:

```
  data_array = {};

  $.ajax({
    url:"Ajax/Path1",           
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {

          data.d.results.forEach(function (data) {

        data_array[data.ID] = {};
        data_array[data.ID][data.description] = {};

        });//foreach end
              console.log(data_array);
    }//sucess end
  });

  $.ajax({
    url:"Ajax/Path2",           
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {

          data.d.results.forEach(function (data) {

        if (data_array[data.ID] === data.ID_of_parent) { data_array[data.data.ID_of_parent] = {}; }

        });//foreach end
            console.log(data_array);
    }
  });
```

Its with the second Ajax where I cant find a way to look trough the existing array, match the child's ID_of_parent to the parent's ID and merge the data.

Then I hoping to do something like

```
dara_array.forEach(function (data) {
    $("#my_table tbody").append("<tr>"+
    "<td>"+data.ID+"</td>"+
    "<td>"+data.Description+"</td>"+
    "<td>"+data.Start+"</td>"+
    "<td>"+data.End+"</td>"+
    "<td>"+data.Hours+"</td>"+
    "<td>"+data.Night_or_Day+"</td>"+  
    "</tr>"); 
});
```

Would anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: When you try and access the array from the second Ajax call, what output do you see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/tj6bcjos/9/
tested.  data1 is the parent, data2 is the children

```
for each (p in data1.d.results){
   var pId = p.ID;

  //find the child
  var children = data2.d.results.filter(function(d){

    return d.ID_of_parent == pId
  })

  var s=[], e=[], h=[], n=[] //start, end  hours...
  for each (c in children)
  {

      s.push(c.Start);
      e.push(c.End);
      h.push(c.Hours);
      n.push(c.Day_or_night);

  }
  var rw = '<tr><td>'+p.ID+'</td><td>'+p.description+'</td><td>'+
      s.join('<br>')+'</td><td>'+e.join('<br>')+'</td><td>'+h.join('<br>')
      +'</td><td>'+n.join('<br>')+'</td></tr>'
  console.log(rw)

    $('#my_table tbody').append(rw);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer Chungtinhlakho, how would you insert this code in the jsfiddle example? https://jsfiddle.net/tj6bcjos/2/

Comment: Thank you so much, was wondering why I couldnt use global variables in an ajax call. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete solution.

```js
var tableMaker = o => {var keys = Object.keys(o[0]),
                   rowMaker = (a,t) => a.reduce((p,c,i,a) => p + (i === a.length-1 ? "<" + t + ">" + c + "</" + t + "></tr>"
                                                                                   : "<" + t + ">" + c + "</" + t + ">"),"<tr>"),
                       rows = o.reduce((r,c) => r + rowMaker(keys.reduce((v,k) => v.concat(c[k]),[]),"td"),rowMaker(keys,"th"));
                   return "<table>" + rows + "</table>";
                  },
    results1 = [{
                ID: "17",
                description: "Description 1"
            }, {
                ID: "22",
                description: "Description 2"
            }, {
                ID: "34",
                description: "Description 3"
            }, {
                ID: "54",
                description: "Description 4"
            }],
    results2 = [{
                ID_of_parent: "17",
                Day_or_night: "day",
                Start: "2016-06-01 08:00",
                End: "2016-06-01 10:00",
                Hours: "2"
            }, {
                ID_of_parent: "17",
                Day_or_night: "day",
                Start: "2016-06-01 13:00",
                End: "2016-06-01 14:00",
                Hours: "1"
            }, {
                ID_of_parent: "17",
                Day_or_night: "night",
                Start: "2016-06-01 21:00",
                End: "2016-06-01 22:00",
                Hours: "1"
            }, {
                ID_of_parent: "22",
                Day_or_night: "day",
                Start: "2016-06-01 09:00",
                End: "2016-06-01 10:00",
                Hours: "1"
            }, {
                ID_of_parent: "22",
                Day_or_night: "day",
                Start: "2016-06-01 14:00",
                End: "2016-06-01 15:00",
                Hours: "1"
            }, {
                ID_of_parent: "54",
                Day_or_night: "day",
                Start: "2016-06-01 13:30",
                End: "2016-06-01 16:00",
                Hours: "2.5"
            }],
  desclut = results1.reduce((p,c) => (p[c.ID] || (p[c.ID] = c.description),p),{}),
   merged = results2.map(e => (e.Description = desclut[e.ID_of_parent], delete e.ID_of_parent,e)),
  myTable = tableMaker(merged);
document.write(myTable);
```

The `tableMaker` function is generic and generates a table from array of objects. The object's properties must be the same and they are used for the table headers and each object constructs a row with its values.

`desclut` is a look up table constructed from `results1`. By doing this we prevent using array.find() type of expensive searches for each element of the `results2` array.

`merged` is the array we get `result1` and `result2` merged in the form that we can use with our `tableMaker` function.

If you want to reorder the properties (table headers) you can use a `merged.reduce((p,c) => {sort the properties accordingly here},{})` instruction.